# Reload mongodb after changing binding address

Tags: mongodb

I am changing the binding address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in the mongodb config file.

Is there any way of just reloading the service and not restarting it?

I am getting below error on reloading the service.

```
sudo systemctl reload mongod
Failed to reload mongod.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit mongod.service.
```

Ubuntu version 16.04.2

MongoDB version 3.2.13

Comment: Is this is a one server DB or a cluster?

Comment: @Udara, its on a single box